# Make hyperlink in webmail back to mvc4 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a webmail and i want the user to press on a picture in the webmail and then be linked back to my mvc project view. I don't have a real domain yet so i can't type www.mysite.com. I want to be able to link to the view without depending on which domain the site is currently running on.

in my webmail i have the body that looks like this:

```
string Body = "<b>Välj ett alternativ!</b><br><br><a href='cid:path4'/><img src='cid:Happy'/ alt='HTML tutorial' width='120' height='120'></a><input type='image' src='cid:Orange'/ name='image' width='120' height='120'><input type='image' src='cid:Mad'/ name='image' width='120' height='120'>";
```

where the cid:path4 is i want the url och what ever so that i linkes me back to my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to format the absolute path into the body text from your controller action (or pass it through to whatever method generates the body):

```
var path = Request.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
var emailBody = String.Format("Your email body. <a href=\"{0}\">Link</a>", path);
```

Or, you could link to another controller action with `Url.Action`:

```
var path = Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController", null, "http");
var emailBody = String.Format("Your email body. <a href=\"{0}\">Link</a>", path);
```

Of course, this all assumes that this email is sent by a controller action - if it's not, it may not be possible to determine the absolute URI of the website.

Comment: How does request.url.absoluteurl; works? How can i tell it whitch url it should contain?

Comment: @DanielGustafsson It takes the URL of the current request, so the link will go back to the action that sent the email. Alternatively, use `Url.Action` as per my edit.